# Cannot find save handler 'memcached' - session startup failed

Tags: php, session, memcached, libmemcached

I have my own simple hosted site on Fasthosts. I was offered to upgrade PHP from 7.0 to 7.3 but I am getting the following error:
Warning: session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'memcached' - session startup failed in /home/xxx

I have tried changing numerous ini settings, including reverting to 'files', all to no avail. It just fails on session_start(). The support staff just say there is no problem! I have now downgraded to 7.0 and it works fine.

I did try 7.1 but received error:
"Warning: Unknown: using touch command with binary protocol is not recommended with libmemcached versions below 1.0.18, please use ascii protocol or upgrade libmemcached in Unknown on line 0".

I will stay with 7.0 but would like a fix as I also have a Charity website for the U3A and cannot risk that failing.

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` and see if memcached is loaded.

Comment: You might want to contact the hosting company

Answer (score 0):

My hosting Company has now come back and having re-checked with the engineers it seems that Memcached is only available on 7.2, which is strange as they only offer 7.0, 7.1 and 7.3.
Oh the woes of being Hosted. Thanks for suggestions.